# I need to compress a PDF to 5 mb (at most, but best exactly)

Tags: pdf, preview, compression

Is there any way to compress a PDF (with the preview / iOS default software) to a certain size in mb (in my case as close as possible under or equal 5 mb)? The actual size right now is (6 scanned pages) 8.8 mb.

If i just use the "normal way" (meaning: finder, export using quarz-filter, compress pdf) i get a far too small and therefore unreadable PDF.

Anyone knowing a good work around?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5):

- Download those filters:
  https://github.com/joshcarr/Apple-Quartz-Filters/archive/master.zip
- Copy them in your mac or user Library ( /Library or /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library) In a Folder named "Filters" (create if doesn't exist).
- Open Preview and export as a PDF.
- Try some of new filter since when you reach the right weight for your pdf.

Answer (score 0):

A great PDF compressor is Ghostscript (`gs`), which is native in most Linux distributions and easily installable for Mac OS X and Windows.

[Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3751/daniel) summarizes [summarizes it best here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller/19047#19047), with the key quote being his preferred options:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
    -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf
```